# MFC/Activex and fire it's evnet after waitforsingleobject

Tags: visual-c++

my project is a dialog base and activeX container that have event .
when i call a function of activex and wait to fire it's event (with WaitForSingleObject), the application stops and the event doesn't happen until time-out, after time out it will happen.

```
void COcxTesDlg::OnBnClickedButton1()
{
hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, L"testEvent");
ocxObj.ocxFunction();
DWORD res = ::WaitForSingleObject(hEvent, 10000);
if(res != WAIT_OBJECT_0)
    AfxMessageBox(L"Time Out");
else
    AfxMessageBox(L"before Time Out");

//--- to do some works after ocx event
//---
}

void COcxTesDlg::ocxEventFunc()
{
   SetEvent(hEvent);
}
```

i always see 'Time Out' MessageBox, but if i don't call the WaitForSingleObject() the ocxEventFunc() happens sooner than 1000ms

i want to do some works **after** event without waiting a lot of time.
please help me.

Comment: instead calling waitforsingleobject, i call AfxMessageBox(L"Please wait..."), this doesn't make stop the dialog events then my ocx event happens. after the ocx event, user can close the Message Box .

Answer (score 0):

Of course it does: you are asking your program to wait, and it waits.

Based on your description of what you are trying to do, your design is fundamentally broken: You are inside a message handler, in your main thread and you call `WaitForSingleObject`. That suspends execution of that thread, which handles all the user interface - and your program if you have only one thread - until the event is signaled or until the timeout expires.

You should rethink your design. Without knowing more it's not easy to suggest alternatives. One possibility is this:

Make a note of the start time (e.g. call `GetTickCountEx` and store the result).

Loop while `start_time - current_time < timeout` value. Inside the loop call `WaitForSingleObject` with `0` for the timeout. That call will *not* block and will return immediately: if it returns `WAIT_OBJECT_0` then the OCX has completed. If it returns `WAIT_TIMEOUT` it means the OCX hasn't completed. You can then do whatever work you want.

Answer (score 0):

You already have a function that is called when the event happens. Use it.

```
void COcxTesDlg::OnBnClickedButton1()
{
ocxObj.ocxFunction();
}

void COcxTesDlg::ocxEventFunc()
{
//--- to do some works after ocx event
//---
}
```

Comment: i need some objects, to do some works, that they are Accessible just in 'OnBnClickedButton1' function. then i can't write 'some works' codes in event function